# Subscription disposal -- does it wait for subscription action to end?

Tags: system.reactive, idisposable

```
var sub = observable.Subscribe(data => my_action(data));
```

When I dispose the `sub` variable it will unsubscribe. Ok, but when doing so will it wait for `my_action` to end if it was already called?

*Update 1: I ask for conscious decision, not some side-effects. Compare this to Threading.Timer -- in order to wait for action you have to call special `Dispose` method.*

*Update 2: I ask for **waiting** for action to end, not to **cancel** the action.*

Comment: The code inside `my_action` would have to have some explicit cancellation mechanism for it to cancel cleanly. Otherwise if it were to abort the thread that could cause all sorts of issues in your code.

Comment: @Enigmativity, see my update, waiting!=canceling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. If the action and the dispose occur on the same thread, then the disposal will happen after the action completes. If the action runs on a different thread to the disposal then they occur independently and it is possible for the disposal to occur while action is executing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so in other words, disposal does have any code to wait for action, correct? :-) See my remark about Timer.

Comment: @astrowalker - What does "disposal does have any code to wait for action" mean?

Comment: @Enigmativity, sorry, missed "not", it should read "disposal does **not** have any...". It means, I rephrased, and I say, that disposal does not wait for action to finish, because it does not contain any code responsible handling the wait.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>If your question is, will subscription-disposal ever cancel an action triggered by a prior observation, the answer is no.</strike>

**EDIT**:

To answer your clarified question, the short answer is no. Disposal is *scheduled* immediately. Depending on your thread/scheduler situation, it will then either be executed immediately, or executed when there's an availaible thread.

Comment: Thank you, but my question is about waiting, not canceling.

Comment: Updated for clarification.